# How is git rev-list different from git rev-list --date-order?

Tags: git

According to `git rev-list`'s man page:

> By default, the commits are shown in reverse chronological order.

And the explanation for the `--date-order` option is:

> This option is similar to --topo-order in the sense that no parent comes before all of its children, but otherwise things are still ordered in the commit timestamp order.

What's the difference if I specify `--date-order` or if I don't? In both these case, are commits order by committer date or author date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default git does not impose "no parent before child" and seems to do a depth-first traversal of the history. You may end up with the very first commit ever made in your repository somewhere in the middle of the output.

--date-order and --topo-order do impose an additional "no parent before child" constraint on the output order.

Recent git versions have a [somewhat better explanation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-list.html#_commit_ordering):

> --date-order
>
> Show no parents before all of its children are shown, but otherwise show commits in the commit timestamp order.
>
> --topo-order 
>   Show no parents before all of its children are shown, and avoid showing commits on multiple lines of history intermixed.
>
> For example, in a commit history like this:
>
> ```
> ---1----2----4----7
>     \              \
>      3----5----6----8---
> ```
>
> where the numbers denote the order of commit timestamps, git rev-list and friends with --date-order show the
>   commits in the timestamp order: 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1.
>
> With --topo-order, they would show 8 6 5 3 7 4 2 1 (or 8 7 4 2 6 5 3
>   1); some older commits are shown before newer ones in order to avoid
>   showing the commits from two parallel development track mixed
>   together.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that the dates referred to are committer dates, not author dates?

Comment: Yes. I believe that's what git manual means by "**commit** timestamps"

Comment: Yeah, I saw that, but it wasn't clear whether the default order also is by committer timestamps. Frankly, I'm struggling to think of a situation where `git rev-list` puts the root commit in the middle of the output, since "By default, the commits are shown in reverse chronological order."

Comment: There may be more than one root :-) Or there may be commits timestamped (intentionally or not) before your root commit.

Comment: So in that case, the documentation is incorrect when it says "By default, the commits are shown in reverse chronological order."

Comment: In reverse chronological order of timestamps in the commits. Said timestamps may not necessarily be in the order of commits. Ordered in chronological order it is possible that the first commit in your repository may not be the last commit printed out by "git rev-list". Things get murkier if you stop to consider that git is a distributed  version control system. What is the very first commit in your repository at the time you created it may not be the commit with the oldest timestamp once you've fetched history from another repository.